# Can I make a custom matcher for Flutter unit or integration tests?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test

I'm writing a unit or integration test for mobile. Can I make a custom matcher?

Comment: I don't think asking 5 "one line" questions in 5 minutes is a good idea. Especially when the documentation is pretty good already. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/matcher/Matcher-class.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create custom [`Matcher`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/matcher/Matcher-class.html) classes and custom [`Finder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/Finder-class.html) classes.

Here's one of Flutter's custom matchers that asserts that the given `Finder` finds a widget that's inside a `Card` widget:

```
class _IsInCard extends Matcher {
  const _IsInCard();

  @override
  bool matches(covariant Finder finder, Map<dynamic, dynamic> matchState) => _hasAncestorOfType(finder, Card);

  @override
  Description describe(Description description) => description.add('in card');
}
```

The [`Matcher`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/matcher/Matcher-class.html) class is not part of the Flutter framework. It is defined in [`package:mathcer`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/matcher). Flutter inherits it from [`package:test`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test). All Flutter's own Matcher classes are custom implementations of it.

Flutter's [test framework](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/flutter_test-library.html) has lots of [custom matchers](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/matchers.dart) and [custom finders](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/finders.dart) you can learn from.